# Validity of geometric series formula for $r=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I can convince myself of the geometric series formula

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}$$

for $0<|r|<1$, but not for $|r|<1$ because I don't believe the formula for $r=0$.

If $r=0$, we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n = 0^0 + 0^1 + 0^2 + \ldots$$

It is not clear to me what this sum equals, much less that it equals $\frac{1}{1-0}=1$. However, every source that I've consulted says that the result holds for $-1<r<1$.

Can anyone justify the $r=0$ case? Must we simiply accept $0^0=1$ in this context?

Comment: if $r=0$ it's not geometric series. By definition, ratio of consecutive terms should be the same.

Comment: There are lots of ways to define geometric series, @Vasya. One is that $a_{n+1}a_{n-1}=a_n^2.$ In any event, this nit-pick doesn't resolve the question.

Comment: Then why does every textbook (even good ones, like Spivak) give the formula for $-1 < r <1$?

Comment: There are lots of answers to the question "Why is $0^0=1?$" It is by definition, but there are reasons we define it that way. Some are convenience, some are for numeric reasons (there are simple set theory and number theory reasons that we define $0^0=1.$

Comment: If $r=0$ is allowed, the first term can be any number and $0^0=1$ does not help

Comment: @Vasya The first term can be only $1$.

Comment: Let's say that a correct/umabiguous version of the formula in question is $1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n=\dfrac{1}{1-r}$ for $|r|<1$.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, $0^0=1$. Therefore, the sum *is* $1$.

Comment: Why is $0^0=1$ in this context? Is it different in other contexts?

Comment: The first paragraph here suggests that context matters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero

Comment: @mathclassfromscratch No, it says there is no agreed upon value for $0^0$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes, and then the second sentence says that context matters.

Comment: @mathclassfromscratch The justifications come from different contexts. That doesn't mean that there are provable values for $0^0$ based on different contexts. Either way, I can say this sum equals $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ and there is no context in which you can prove that $1$ is a better answer.

Comment: @JohnDouma I think I follow you now. So I could *argue* (rather than prove) that 1 is a better answer than $\frac{1}{\sqrt \pi}$ here because 1 gives us the result for $-1 < r < 1$?

Comment: Yes. You can make a case to define $0^0=1$.

Comment: One more point: to obtain the summation formula, both sides of an equation are multiplied by $r$ which is nonsense if $r=0$

Answer (score 2):

Power series come up everywhere in mathematics, necessitating a convenient form to represent them. The easiest form is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (x-x_0)^k
$$
In order for this to represent a proper function, we should be able to substitute any value of $x$ into it. If you do not accept the convention $0^0=1$, you then run into problems when $x=x_0$; the value of the power series at that point is supposed to be $a_0$, but you instead get it is $a_0\cdot 0^0$. To avoid this, you would have to instead write
$$
a_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k (x-x_0)^k
$$ 
which is inconvenient. Therefore, for ease of notation, we stipulate that $0^0=1$ in the context of power series. This is the context of $\sum_{n\ge 0}r^n$. See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero#Polynomials_and_power_series

for a confirmation of this.

---

As a side note, there are an overwhelming number of situations where it is convenient to define $0^0=1$, and there are no situations where it is convenient to assume otherwise.

Comment: What number can be considered overwhelming comparing with zero?

Answer (score 1):

Note a geometric sequence is defined in general as being $\{a, ar, ar^2, ar^3, \ldots \}$, i.e., where each term is $t_i = ar^i$ for $i \ge 0$.

Your statement of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}$ is actually a specific case of the more general one, such as provided at [Geometric series: Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) of

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ar^n = \frac{a}{1-r} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

where $|r| \lt 1$, and in your case $a = 1$. As such, if $r = 0$, then the geometric sequence would be $\{1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots \}$ and, thus, it's clear that the sum is $1$. Plugging $a = 1$ and $r = 0$ into \eqref{eq1} gives this same result. Also, by the definition of the sequence, it needs to use "$0^0 = 1$" in the LHS of \eqref{eq1} to get that the first term is $a$. This is due to, for $r \neq 0$, that $r^0 = 1$, so $\lim_{\, r \to 0}r^0 = 1$.

Note that some definitions of geometric sequences requires that $r \neq 0$. However, as you can see, the general equation can still work even if you use $r = 0$.

Comment: This answer basically just sidesteps the problem by defining a geometric sequence informally. You could have also defined it as `1,r,r^2,...` and be done with it. The original question basically asks why when we define a geometric series as `a_n=ar^n` we should have `a_0=a0^0` be `a` rather than anything else. You're just assuming that this is indeed the correct definition from the start.

Comment: @user3329719 The original definition of a geometric series that I learned, and as also defined by the referenced article, is as I state at the top. Although I define it informally initially, I also define the terms formally as $t_i$. In addition, as for why, in $a_0 = a 0^0$, it makes sense for $0^0 = 1$, I also explain that with my statement about the limit as $r \to 0$, so I'm showing why it makes sense for $0^0 = 1$ instead of assuming this at that time. As such, I'm not clear exactly what issues you have with my answer.